# smtplib not sending email when running as cronjob

Tags: python, cron, smtplib

I have a python script which is executed every minute as a cronjob. The script communicates with different sensors and a database, calculates some values and stores them into the database.
After calculation i am generating a pdf out of the information in the db which is sent via email to me.
For the sending process i use `smtplib`.

When executing the script manually over the terminal it is working fine. Somehow the sending part fails when executed as cronjob. It's no network issue since the script is communicating with the database for the calculation part.

Did anyone encounter this kind of error before? Thanks.

Comment: (1) Are there any error messages or tracebacks logged?  PLease [edit] the question to include them (2) Cronjobs usually run with a different environment to standard users, this is often the cause of errors.

Comment: I wish i had some error logs. There are no errors thrown.